# Undefined term in a series: right approach?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let's take the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-7n+12}$$

Factorizing the denominator we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-7n+12}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-4)(n-3)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n-4}-\frac{1}{n-3}$$

Then we have the partial sum

$$S_n=(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2})+(-\frac{1}{2}+1)+...+(1-\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})+...+(\frac{1}{n-4}-\frac{1}{n-3})$$

It is easy to see the pattern in which the terms cancel out, and one would expect $S_n=-\frac{1}{3}$.

The problem is that, in order to not deal with the undefined terms when $n=3$ and $n=4$ I just skip them (hence the first $...$ in the partial sum), eager to just see the pattern.

This can't be any less than cheating! But what other way is there to work with a partial sum that has undefined terms?

Comment: You are correct to be concerned about the undefined terms.  A sum which contains undefined terms *will be undefined*!  Your summation should have started at $n=5$ instead for it to have made sense.

Comment: The series should be calculated from $\;n=5,...\infty\;$...or otherwise defined.

Comment: @WaveX I wouldn't trust WolframAlpha on this. If you factor the denominator, then [it say the series converges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+1+to+infinity+1%2F%28%28n-4%29%28n-3%29%29), which is false.

Comment: @kccu I see. I wonder what makes it think that. The way it handles the calculation perhaps? In any case I'll remove my comment

Comment: @WaveX There is an algorithm to sum a series of rational functions, which doesn't need to check if some denominators vanish. In this case essentially doing the telescoping in the post. On the other hand, note that 'undefined' only means 'someone hasn't defined it', or 'in some context it is convenient to not include them as defined'. It is not hard to give a definition of those singular terms such that the sum of the series implied by that definition is $-\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Without skipping the terms for $n=3,4$ the series does not make any sense regardless of however we may write it. It is not a question of divergence or rearrangement. The terms $a_3, a_4$ of the given series are not defined. As such, in the most pedantic sense, the series $\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-7n+12}$ is not really defined. What is defined is $\sum\limits_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{n^2-7n+12}+\sum\limits_{5}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-7n+12}$.